# PowerShell script not executing correctly on network drive on SSMS Availability Group. Error returns as "not digitally signed"

Tags: sql-server, powershell

As the title says, I'm attempting to run a script via an SSMS job on a network drive directory.

I have set the execution policy to bypass, unrestricted and remote signed but it always says it hasn't been digitally signed.

I have also tried placing this within the script I'm calling:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock { Get-ExecutionPolicy } | Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force -Scope CurrentUser`

Here's the error I'm getting:

`File \\qaappdata\SQL\***\SimpleTest.ps1 cannot be loaded...is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. The error information returned by PowerShell is:   + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess`

Putting the script on the local D:\ drive works fine and does what I need it to do. But placing the script on a network drive is more convenient and ideal.

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted
```

^ Execution policy of the server

Comment: The error is UnauthorizedAccess.  I would check the SSMS error logs.  Also use SQL Serer Management Studio and log into Server.  Then check in the explorer under management the log files.  Is DataBase attached to server or you are trying to use an MDF file?  What is the connection string?

Comment: @jdweng The issue isn't related to permissions on the SSMS side, at least not as I understand it. When I run the job on the D:\ via the SSMS job it is able to find the script and execute things fine. It's only when I adjust the job step to run on the network drive. 
This is the command in the SSMS job step: 
cmd.exe /c %SystemRoot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile "\\qaappdata\SQL\***\SimpleTest.ps1"

Comment: You are making a connection to the database.  The most likely reason is the connection is failing.  Check the log files in SSMS and see what error you are getting.  Either the connection did not complete or the credentials are wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading your question... how do you expect an unsigned script to be able to execute enough such that it can change the execution policy to allow unsigned scripts to execute? Have you considered signing the script that's on the network drive? Signing the bootstrapper script that changes the execution policy? Creating a temporary SQL Agent job, or a predecessor step, that executes `Set-ExecutionPolicy` as a command, rather than a PowerShell script file?